# Using Ansible Variables in InSpec test

Tags: ansible, devops, inspec

I'm currently building reusable Playbooks which is fine for InSpec testing post deployment as I know exactly how it will always look.

I'm moving onto configuration items that change build on build with the use of variables in ansible. Is there way in which I can build InSpec tests that will ensure the variable entered has been correctly used without hard coding the variable into InSpec before running the test?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could make use of --attr switch. You can pass a file through a command like this:

```
inspec exec . --attrs attributes/client-attributes.yml
```

Take a look at this [article](http://www.anniehedgie.com/inspec-basics-9).